# Unity webapp is not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, webapps, webapp-development

I created an [Unity webapp for Telegram](https://launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram):

It works perfect in Ubuntu 13.10.

In Ubuntu 14.04 is not working:

- I open the [Webogram](http://zhukov.github.io/webogram/) web.
- Firefox is asking about to install the webapp > I click yes.
- Problem: No icon appears in the Unity Launcher.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

PS: How can you test it? I'm working in a PPA, but now, you can install [this installer](https://launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram/0.0.1/0.0.1/+download/unity-webapps-telegram_0.0.1_all.deb).

Then visit [Webogram](http://zhukov.github.io/webogram/) web. Unity will ask you about to install the Webapp.

Comment: Are you using that webapp from webbrowser-app? Or are you using Firefox or Chrom{e,ium}? I think they only work in webbrowser-app in 14.04. Also, you should use `https` URLs for pages on github.

Comment: @dobey, I added the mkdir ;) I'm using Firefox, Firefox asks about to install the webapp, but the launcher not appears. I did the same in Ubuntu 13.10 and all works perfect.

Comment: About the http protocol, I created this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram/+bug/1310190

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, The .desktop file was missing ;) Now it works. I'll enjoy Telegram now with Unity :D
I'm just testing the webapp, if you find something weird, please, tell me here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-webapps-telegram

How could you test it? Just run this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/unity-webapps-telegram ; sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-telegram
```

Cheers!

Comment: Now I got "W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/costales/unity-webapps-telegram/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found"

Comment: You're using Ubuntu 12.04 and that webapp is working just in Ubuntu 13.10 or 14.04 ;)